# Why do I get a error 400 trying to insert a CSV file with Google Drive SDK?

Tags: php, csv, google-drive-api, google-sheets, mime-types

I have some old code that inserts a csv file into a Google Drive account and it was opened by Google Spreadsheets by default.

Couple days ago I started to receive this error message:

> There is some problems with the Google connection. Please, try again.
>   (Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?convert=false&uploadType=multipart&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
>   (400) Invalid mime type provided)

Here is some of the code:

```
public function createDriveFile($tmpFilePath,$title,$fileMimetype = '',$description = '',$googleDocmimeType = ''){
      $file = new Google_DriveFile();
      $file->setTitle($title);
      $file->setDescription($description);

      $data = file_get_contents($tmpFilePath);
      $optParams = array('data' => $data);

      if($fileMimetype != '' ) {
        if($fileMimetype === 'text/csv' ) {
          $optParams['convert'] = false;
          $optParams['mimeType'] = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet';
        } else {
          $optParams['convert'] = true;
        }
        $file->setMimeType( $fileMimetype );
      }
      if ($googleDocmimeType != ''){
        $optParams['mimeType'] = $googleDocmimeType;
      }

      $createdFile = $this->_driveService->files->insert($file, $optParams);

      return $createdFile;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that it is sending `'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'` as mimetype.

Here a call to that function:

```
$createFileInfo = $googleOauth->createDriveFile('/tmp/file.csv', 'file.csv','text/csv');
```

I made some tests changing the value of the `'convert'` parameter to `true` and didn't work.

Comment: Might want to clarify and tag the language you're coding in, I assume it's php but tagging it correctly will help the correct wizards find your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be sending it with the mimeType of `text/csv`. Google Sheets will still be able to open it, so there is no need to misrepresent it as a true Google Spreadsheet.